# Struts2 Usage of RequestAware Interface

Tags: struts2

If my action class is as per below:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->

package org.tutorial.struts2.action;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.RequestAware;
import org.tutorial.struts2.service.TutorialFinder;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class TutorialAction implements Action, RequestAware {
    private String language;
    private String bestTutorialSite;

    public String execute() {
        System.out.println(language);
        setBestTutorialSite(new TutorialFinder().getBestTutorialSite(language));
        System.out.println(bestTutorialSite);       
        if (getBestTutorialSite().contains("Java"))
            return SUCCESS;
        else
        return ERROR;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getBestTutorialSite() {
        return bestTutorialSite;
    }

    public void setBestTutorialSite(String bestTutorialSite) {
        this.bestTutorialSite = bestTutorialSite;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRequest(Map<String, Object> requestObj) {
        System.out.println(bestTutorialSite);
        requestObj.put("message", bestTutorialSite);
    }

}
```

When this action is invoked prior to the execute method, the language is already populated by Struts2 framework. In the execute method the `setBestTutorialSite` method is to populate the private field `bestTutorialSite`.

Now I thought of setting this private field `bestTutorialSite` into the request attributes (in the `setRequest` method). However I notice that this method is invoked first before any private field (like the language) is populated. Hence in the `setRequest` method, the system print of `bestTutorialSite` is always null.

I thought I was able to set this attribute with the `bestTutorialSite` (captured from the execute method) prior to calling the JSP page.

I don't think i fully grasp the understanding of Struts2 flow - obviously! :OP

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. In any case, the ordering of interceptors will determine which is set first, the request, or the parameters.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm trying to set bestTutorialSite object as an attribute in the request object. Problem is the bestTutorialSite is null in the setRequest method eventhough in the execute method the bestTutorialSite do have a value. If i can set the bestTutorialSite value in the request object as an attribute in the setRequest method then this can be used later in some JSP pages.

Comment: That's not how to expose values to JSP in Struts 2. Values should be exposed as action properties, or as part of the model exposed by a ModelDriven action. But as I said, interceptor order determined which will be set first, parameters or the request map.

Comment: what is the need for you to set to request parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using *defaultStack* which looks like this:

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="profiling"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
        <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</interceptor-stack>
```

as you can see, *servletConfig* interceptor is before *params* interceptor which means first Request will be set on your action (with *servletConfig*) and then your action will be populated with request parameters (with *params*).

What you want to achieve is to change the order of the interceptors which can be harmful when used in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I think request interceptor will execute first,After that the execute() method will execute.
It might be the problem.